# After transferring project from my username to my organization, my username shows me as maintainer instead of owner

Tags: gitlab

Another project that was created directly in the organization shows me as owner.

Is there a way to fix this in the settings?

I checked the settings/members page, and the only way I see is to click the "Leave" button next to my maintainer status, and then *hope* that I will automatically be marked as the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, that's safe to do.

When you transfer a project, all roles are kept "as is". Since by default, you're a Maintainer on the personal project, when you transfer it, it keeps that role for you.

When you have a role in the group, it will inherit the role, unless a role is specified for the project. By deleting your role at the project level, you're just deleting the specified project-specific role. Once you do, you should show up as an Owner (inheriting it from the group).

Comment: Indeed I just used this to delete my "maintainer" role, and then the "owner" role popped up. Thanks!